# How to show Loading by making a POST request on changing star rating following bloc pattern in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter project, I am following **bloc architecture** pattern to make a **POST request**.

I have 2 model classes one for setting the body of my POST request- **ModelPostRating** and another for receiving the response- **ModelPostRatingResponse** from POST request.

Then, I have created one class **ProductRatingPostRequestProvider** for making API call with setting up the body and header part for the request.

**ProductRatingPostRequestProvider.dart**

```
class ProductRatingPostRequestProvider {
  Client client = Client();

  Future<ModelPostRatingResponse> postLoginResponse(
      ModelPostRating modelPostRating) async {
    Response response;
    print("Product rating request send");
    print("productId: ${modelPostRating.productId}");
    print("value: ${modelPostRating.value}");

    response = await client.post('${my_base_url}/rating',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: json.encode({
          "productId": "${modelPostRating.productId}",
          "value": "${modelPostRating.value}"
        }));

    print('response: ${response.body}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return ModelPostRatingResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load post");
    }
  }
}
```

Then created another class **ProductPostRatingBloc** follwoing the bloc pattern-

**ProductPostRatingBloc.dart**

```
class ProductPostRatingBloc {
  final _repository = RepositoryProductPostRating();
  final _postRatingFetcher = PublishSubject<ModelPostRatingResponse>();

  Observable<ModelPostRatingResponse> get postRatingResponse =>
      _postRatingFetcher.stream;

  fetchRatingPostResponse(
      ModelPostRating modelPostRating, BuildContext context) async {
    ModelPostRatingResponse modelPostRatingResponse =
        await _repository.postRatingRequest(modelPostRating);

    print("post rating status: ${modelPostRatingResponse.message}");
    showMaterialDialog(modelPostRatingResponse.message, context);
    _postRatingFetcher.sink.add(modelPostRatingResponse);
  }
}

final blocProductPostRating = ProductPostRatingBloc();
```

Now, in the class where I show all the widgets, I have following code to to make **POST request** while changing the rating value like below-

```
 Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              StarRating(
                size: 25.0,
                rating: rating2.toDouble(),
                color: Colors.orange,
                borderColor: Colors.grey,
                starCount: starCount,
                onRatingChanged: (rating) => setState(
                      () {
                    this.rating2 = rating.toInt();

                    ModelPostRating modelPostRating =
                    new ModelPostRating(
                        productId: "1", value: "$rating2");

                    blocProductPostRating.fetchRatingPostResponse(
                        modelPostRating, context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

**Now, the problem is--------**

When I press for changing the rating, while the **POST request** takes time to give response, I want to show Loading and after getting the response it will be dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

although its been too long to answer this but yet i would like to share my way of doing the same thing using bloc pattern.
i would have rendered rating widget inside blocbuilder state and on rating change i would have called my bloc event to change the rating which would streams the awaited response from server.
in bloc builder i would have rendered loading indicator until the bloc state changes to rating changed state.

snippet of bloc class

```
@override
Stream<BlocStateClass> mapEventToState(BlocEventClass event) async* {
if (event is ChangeRatingEvent) {
  try {
   // here you can make your api call to update the rating and get the response
   RatingMaster ratingMaster=
        await repository.changeRating(event.rating);

    yield RatingUpdatedState(ratings: ratingMaster);
  } catch (e) {
    yield BlockErrorState(message: e.toString());
  }
}
```

}

and i would render the rating widget using following code

```
BlocBuilder<BlocClass, BlocStateClass>(
     bloc: _xyzBloc, // bloc instance
     builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is InitState) {
           return buildDefaultRating();
        }else if (state is LoadingState) {
           return buildLoading();
        } else if (state is BlockErrorState) {
           return buildErrorUi(state.message);
        } else if (state is RatingUpdatedState) {
           return _updateratingWidget(state.ratings, context);
        }
})
```

and this line would help in adding the event to the bloc on onRatingChanged function

```
_xyzBloc.add(ChangeRatingEvent(rating: rating));
```

i hope this could help someone in need.